# Comment traduire « First World problem » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

Comment traduit-on un/le « [First World problem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first_world_problem) » (aussi [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World_problem)) en emploi informel pour les *frustrations/difficultés éprouvées par des gens en l'absence de problèmes plus importants dans les [pays industrialisés](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17020975)* (une manière de l'exprimer parmi d'autres). Le [*problème du premier monde*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probl%C3%A8me_du_premier_monde) est-il adéquat ou non et pourquoi ?

Comment: J'entend souvent (en français de Belgique) l'expression en anglais "First World Problem" sans que personne de ma génération (<35 ans) ne trouve ca bizarre. Néanmoins j'ai du expliquer a mes parents (>55ans)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je ne pense pas que *premier monde* soit encore utilisé ni qu'il soit forcément compris.

La seule expression courante qui me vient à l'esprit est :

> Problème de riche.

Comment: Quand je jase avec un ami, souvent on en vient à qualifier ce dont on discute de _First World problem_ mais on trébuche dans la prononciation, l'ordre des mots etc. Dirais-tu que en France les gens en général sont familiers avec ce mot composé-là ? Par ailleurs _riche_ me semble plus intense que _personnes des pays industrialisés_ ou Occidentaux. Comprendrais-tu « de privilégiés » ?

Comment: *Problème de riche* est une expression connue et utilisée. Les pays occidentaux, c'est les pays riches, indépendamment de la pauvreté qu'on peut y trouver.  https://maman.lardons.cz/lecologie-de-toute-facon-cest-un-probleme-de-riches-oui-mais/ https://www.igen.fr/timeline/watch/mickael/un-probleme-de-riche-comment-gerer-deux-apple-watch-sur-un-iphone

Comment: Privilégié est souvent un euphémisme pour riche...

Comment: Variante déjà entendue avec une pointe de sarcasme: *les riches aussi ont leurs problèmes.*

Comment: Si on veut être sûr que ce soit compris par opposition aux pays pauvres/tiers monde (et pas une opposition riche/pauvre dans un même pays), on pourrait dire : "Problème de pays riche" ou "problème de pays développé"